# R: Dynamic Regression with ARIMA model using xreg, make use of step function?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, arima, stepwise-regression, dynamic-regression

This might fit better here than on stackoverflow, I guess.

I was [trying to build a dynamic regression model with the dynlm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139874/r-dynamic-linear-regression-with-dynlm-package-how-to-predict) package, but it did not work out. After reading [this](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) by Hyndman, I now switched to an ARMAX model:

```
y_t = a_1*x1_t + a_2*x2_t + ... + a_k*xk_t + n_t
```

where the error term follows an ARMA model

```
n_t ~ ARMA(p,q)
```

So far I am using the function `auto.arima(y, xreg=cbind(x1, ..., xk))` from the `forecast`package, which is doing the job!

As a benchmark I am running a pure multiple regression with `lm()`, where I make use of the `step()` function to kick out non relevant variables (about 100 variables, from which 96 are dummies) to optimize the model according to `AIC`.

The in-sample forecasting for both models is more or less equal. As the ARMAX model always includes **all** independent variables `(x1, ..., xk)`, I am pretty sure that, if I could apply the `step()` function on it, I would achieve a further improvement here.

The problem is that the `step()` function does not work on `auto.arima()`?!

Do you have any suggestions how I could still do this? Or would I need a totally new approach?

(I have not provide a reproducible example, as this is a rather general question of which methods/functions/packages to use. If the question is not clear enough, please tell me and I will try to provide one)